# Error al crear una base de datos desde postgresql

Tags: pgadmin

Estoy intentando ejecutar este código:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "dmenu";

CREATE DATABASE "dmenu" WITH OWNER postgres;
```

Y me sale este error:

> ERROR:  transacción abortada, las órdenes serán ignoradas hasta el fin de bloque de transacción
> SQL state: 25P02

¿Alguien sabe a qué es debido esto? Las sentencias me funcionan cuando las ejecuto por separado.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en tus dobles comillas. Debes de usar estas ``` `` ``` en lugar de `" "` comillas dobles, tampoco las confundas con las comillas simples `' '`

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `dmenu`;

CREATE DATABASE `dmenu` WITH OWNER postgres;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo debes ejecutar una sola transacción, en este caso

`CREATE DATABASE "dmenu" WITH OWNER postgres;`

Comment: Hola! ¿Cómo se diferencia esta respuesta de la que dio BaruchSpinoza hace un tiempo?

Comment: En que solo tiene la línea para crear la base de datos, has probado si la solución de Baruch Spinoza funciona de postgreSQL?

Comment: De hecho ya la comenté acorde con la [documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdatabase.html). Y tu respuesta tampoco provee una solución a la pregunta del OP. De hecho, las instrucciones en la pregunta funcionan desde un cliente estándar (digamos, DBeaver).

Comment: La pregunta hace referencia a pgAdmin

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta a esto es que se debe configurar pgAdmin para que no cree bloques de transacción implícitos (revisando la configuración en [Preferencias](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/preferences.html)). Eso hará que esa consulta falle. No deben usarse bloques de transacción `begin - end` porque la [documentación dice claramente](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createdatabase.html) que no deben correrse dentro de esos bloques.

> CREATE DATABASE cannot be executed inside a transaction block.

En caso de duda, correr las mismas instrucciones usando psql puede resolver dudas, poniendo todo en un solo archivo y usando

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -a -f "C:\prueba.sql"
```

Usando una ruta absoluta al archivo que queremos probar

Answer (score -1):

Es probable que tengas que hacer una transacción para cada una de las sentencias.

```sql
BEGIN;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS "dmenu";
COMMIT;
-- Termina una y comienza la otra
BEGIN;
CREATE DATABASE "dmenu" WITH OWNER postgres;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Lo probé pero me sigue mostrando el mismo error, incluso cuando ejecuto cada bloque por separado, desde el BEGIN; hasta el COMMIT;. Gracias por responder.

Comment: Comprendo. Te recomiendo revisar las sentencias que se ejecutan anteriores a estas para comprobar que no sea algo más lo que está fallando.

Comment: Las instrucciones DDL no requieren bloques de transacción.